# Methodology to copy data from one machine to many others in a fast way

Tags: bash, rsync, file-copy

I found some bottleneck on my workflow which is as follows. I do have one master computer which needs to send data to other node machines. This is done in a for loop such as:

`for all nodes: rsync <Options> <Master> <Node>`

This works quite nice if the amount of nodes is not to large e.g. 4 or 8 (copying time around 2 min). However, its a linear curve. For 16 nodes it takes around 3.5 minutes and for 128 nodes its already 20 minutes (and then this stuff becomes almost the bottleneck of my workflow).

My intention is to get rid of the stupid `for all` loop and do things more like that:

```
1. copy master to node1
wait & check if successfull
2. copy master to node2 && copy node1 to node3
wait & check if successfull
3. copy master to node4 && copy node1 to node5 && copy node3 to node6
wait & check if successfull
...
```

My question: Is there anything in bash available which would help me to do something like that or are there more reliable solutions? I am a bit restricted based on the IT in terms of tools to use. Any suggestion is warmly welcomed.

Another nice thing I have in mind which might be even better:

```
 1. copy master data to memory
 2. send the memory stuff to all nodes simultaneously (if that is possible) and all nodes write simultaneously
```

Maybe `rsync` can handle something like that as well? Any idea is warmly welcomed.

For information purposes, I already created some test-script which is given below and can also be optimised. E.g., the `master` stuff is not necessary as we can handle, `node0` as the `master` node. Hence, the code could be further reduced. However, there is still the check, if the copying was successful missing etc. - just as an example of my idea? You can copy it, create a master folder, put some files in, and create 128 nodes. Then run the script and compare with a serial copy (standard approach given in the script). Its faster even though we work on one machine/HDD only (hence, not really representative).

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Tobias Holzman
# 25.03.2023
#
# Description
#   Script that speeds-up the function serial copying from master to nodes
#   by using other nodes at which the data are already copied. 
#
#   Standard Approach:
#   forAll(nodes, nodei)
#   {
#       rsync <masterData> <nodei_path>
#   }   
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function copyToNode ()
{
    # Simple check if folder exist
    if [ ! -d $1/triSurface ]
    then
        echo "Error"
        return 0
    fi

    rsync -av --progress $1/triSurface $2/ > /dev/null &

    return 0
}


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

t1=$(date +%s)

# How many nodes we have (for test purpose)
nCopy=$(ls -d node* | wc -l)

nodesEmpty=()
nodesCopied=()
copyNodes=()

# Create a string array that includes all node names
for i in $(seq 0 $nCopy)
do
    nodesEmpty+=("node$i")
done


echo "We need to copy the data from master to $nCopy nodes"
echo "----------------------------------------------------"

i=0
done=0
dataAtHowManyNodes=0
while true
do
    i=$((i+1))

    # Copy array nodesCopied which we work with in one loop 
    # as we dont want to change the original array
    copyNodes=("${nodesCopied[@]}")

    echo ""
    echo " ++ Copy run #$i"
    echo " ++ Remaining nodes to which we need to copy: ${nodesEmpty[@]}"
    echo " ++ Available nodes used for copy           : ${nodesCopied[@]}"

    echo "  |-> parallel copy sequences: $dataAtHowManyNodes"

    # Only master copy
    if [ $dataAtHowManyNodes -eq 0 ]
    then

        nodeToCopy=${nodesEmpty[0]}

        echo "  |    |-> master to $nodeToCopy"

        copyToNode "master" "$nodeToCopy"

        # Add node to nodesCopied
        nodesCopied+=("$nodeToCopy")

        # Remove node from nodesEmpty
        unset nodesEmpty[0]

        # Update the index
        nodesEmpty=(${nodesEmpty[*]})

    else

        for ((j=0; j<$dataAtHowManyNodes; j++))
        do

            echo "  |-> copy sequenz $j"

            nodeToCopy=${nodesEmpty[0]}

            # Master to node copy
            if [ $j -eq 0 ]
            then

                echo "  |    |-> master to $nodeToCopy"

                copyToNode "master" "$nodeToCopy"

                # Add node to nodesCopied
                nodesCopied+=("$nodeToCopy")

                # Remove node from nodesEmpty
                unset nodesEmpty[0]

                # Update the index
                nodesEmpty=(${nodesEmpty[*]})

            # Node to node copy
            else

                nodeMaster=${copyNodes[0]}

                # Remove copyNode to ensure its not used again
                unset copyNodes[0]
                # Update the index
                copyNodes=(${copyNodes[*]})

                echo "  |    |-> $nodeMaster to $nodeToCopy"

                copyToNode "$nodeMaster" "$nodeToCopy"

                # Add node to nodesCopied
                nodesCopied+=("$nodeToCopy")

                # Update the index
                nodesCopied=(${nodesCopied[*]})

                # Remove node from nodesEmpty
                unset nodesEmpty[0]

                # Update the index
                nodesEmpty=(${nodesEmpty[*]})

            fi

            # Check if still remaining emptyNodes
            if [ ${#nodesEmpty[@]} -eq 0 ]
            then
                echo " ++ Done ..."
                done=1
                break
            fi
        done

    fi

    wait

    if [ $done -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo ""
        break
    fi

    dataAtHowManyNodes=$(echo "scale=0; 2^$i" | bc)
    echo "  |-> Data are now on $dataAtHowManyNodes nodes"


done
t2=$(date +%s)
dt=$(echo "scale=0; ($t2 - $t1)" | bc)
t=$(echo "scale=2; $dt/60" | bc)

echo "Time = $dt s ($t min)"


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It's always going to take more time to copy data to more hosts.  Even if you run each copy in parallel (bandwidth limits) or farm out the distribution as you're considering (propagation delays, risk of orphaned nodes).  The most common solution to this is to use a network file system (e.g. NFS or GFS, or clustered storage like Ceph or Lustre) so that the nodes don't need to be updated, they always have access to the latest data on the server.  This, of course, has its own set of quirks, performance issues, and risks that need to be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look to programs which use multicast or broadcast dataframes. Then the master won’t be much limited by the network bandwidth since all files will be transmitted once.

`mrsync` can be interesting here. There is also `uftp`.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/173358/multicast-file-transfers

Comment: Thanks, as I am limited to the functionality provided by the IT, let me see what I can do here. Will check it out. Many many thanks. I was expecting that there is already something available :)

Comment: See https://github.com/silpol/mrsync there are explanations… there are 8 steps only for the installation. The comment would be awkward to paraphrase it.  Note that the default parameter uses rsh. You may use `mrsync` with `-r ssh` to be compatible with most installations.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use a network file system, then install and use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to run multiple simultaneous `rsync` commands.

Tune the number of executors so as not to completely saturate bandwidth, since other people and processes need access to the system.

Comment: Will check that as well if `mrsync` is not possible on the system